# Is it safe to call a function after casting it to a void return type?

Tags: c, casting, standards, calling-convention

I have a function that returns a value. Is it safe to cast it to a function pointer type that returns nothing (`void`) and then call it? Does the C standard give enough guarantees to make this safe on any platform, and equivalent to calling the function normally while ignoring the return value?

Bonus question: Is there a standards compliant calling convention that is used in practice on some platform and with which this is not safe to do?

---

Example code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// simple function with a a side-effect;
// it is useful to call even when ignoring the return value
int f(int x) {
    return printf("%d\n", x);
}

typedef void (*fun_t)(int);

int main() {
    fun_t g = &f; // cast to void return type, issues a warning
    g(123);       // <-- is this safe, and equivalent to calling f(123) instead?
    return 0;
}
```

---

Notes:

- This question is concerned only with changing the return type during the cast, not changing the types of any function parameters.
- I know that this is safe on the x86 and x64 platforms I use, assuming the default calling convention, but I would like to know if it is safe in general.
- I know that it is easy to work around this when necessary by writing a wrapper `void fw(int x) { f(x); }`. However, I would still like to know if doing this is safe so that I can better understand the fundamentals of the C language.

Comment: There is no cast in `fun_t g = &f;`. A cast is an explicit operator, a type in parentheses. There is an implicit conversion in an assignment. However, this assignment violates the C standard’s constraints for assignments: For pointers to functions, they must point to compatible types. Because of the constraint violation, the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard (and the implementation must issue a diagnostic), regardless of whether calling a non-void-return-type function through a void-return-type expression were defined.

Comment: You might *think* it is safe on x86 and x64 platforms, but have you tried it for a function that returns a large struct type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

*In addition to tstanisl's answer:*

Consider a big return value as for example this structure:

```c
struct big_t {
    long la[1000000];
};
```

It is allowed as a return type.

Some compilers, including GCC for x86/x64, provide the space for the return value at the caller's site and call the function with a pointer to this space. In your use case, this pointer is not set.

So it is not safe on x86 or x64, nor any other architecture.

Have a lot of fun debugging the crashes!

Answer (score 7):

No. This call invokes *Undefined Behavior*. See [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p8)

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined**.

At link [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p15) one can find rules of compatibility of function types:

> For two function types to be compatible, **both shall specify compatible return types**. Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible types. ...